# Compare two tables and update second table

Tags: php, mysql

There are two tables `table1` and `table2`

`table1` has got two columns `name` and `rank`
`table2` has got only one column `name`

names in `table2` are almost listed in `table1`

I want compare two table and pull rank info from `table1` and update/alter `table2` with `rank`

```
table1

name   |  rank
-------------
john   |  2
mathews|  5
keyn   |  4
emly   |  25
yancy  |  8
stewart|  9
kim    |  12
chris  |  19



  table2

name    
-------
john    
mathews  
keyn     
emly    
yancy    
stewart
```

I want update/insert rank details to table2 from table1
thats it and sorry for the confusion

Comment: Why do you need the full copy of `table1`?

Comment: give some samples of data and expected result... this is easy using sql queries.

Comment: Can you explain also "pull rank info from table1 and update/alter table2 with rank"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem like you want to do something like this:

```
update table2,table1 set table2.rank=table1.rank where table2.name=table1.name
```

This will update the second table with ranks from the first table where the names are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Then put auto increament field of table one in table2. and after this apply left join using these id and pull the info

refer this link

http://www.wellho.net/solutions/mysql-left-joins-to-link-three-or-more-tables.html